# Submit button not inputting

Tags: css

I wanted to try and create a bigger input and submit button box for a simple JS function for my course. However, when I changed the height and font size of my input my submit button no longer functions. I know it has to do with the height because when I remove it, it works. How can I work around this?

I will provide the URL for my website my CSS code that starts the input and the button is on line 273.

http://web.gccaz.edu/~pet2153867/test/

Thanks!

Comment: Please submit a [mcve]. No-one wants to look through hundreds of lines of irrelevant code to find the issue. The idea is, you put in the work to make this issue easy for us to solve.

Comment: Patrick I can't get more specific then line 273 in my css file lol if you read my post I understand my issue has to do specifically with one thing which is height values

Comment: The problem is, in the current state, once this question is solved, and your website is likely to be updated with the correction, there will be absolutely no reference to what the issue was and this question will be useless for any future readers. That's why this site exists in the first place.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll add the code and also have a reference to my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position: relative;  and z-index:9999; to your button style.

```
button {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

this problem caused by H1 Tag. h1 tag crosspvered with your button. removing bottom:70px will also fix your problem.

```
#projects h1 {
position: relative;
bottom: 70px;
}
```